# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row: for carretera Glength

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT c1.matricula, GLength(c1.geometry) as longitud 
FROM carreteras c1
WHERE GLength(c1.geometry) = (
    SELECT GLength(c2.geometry) 
    FROM carreteras c2
);
```

Comment: Yes, it quite probably does. Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: `=` should be `IN`, since the subquery returns multiple rows. But this will return all the rows, since you're just comparing the table with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the subquery returns more than one row, you have to use `IN`:

```
SELECT c1.matricula, GLength(c1.geometry) as longitude
FROM carreteras c1
WHERE GLength(c1.geometry) IN (
    SELECT GLength(c2.geometry)
    FROM carreteras c2
);
```

or `ANY`:

```
SELECT c1.matricula, GLength(c1.geometry) as longitude
FROM carreteras c1
WHERE GLength(c1.geometry) = ANY (
    SELECT GLength(c2.geometry)
    FROM carreteras c2
);
```